# Are there any classes across the d20 systems with really good crafting abilities?

Tags: class-feature, homebrew, crafting

Long story short, my DM is giving us access to class abilities outside of D20 modern/future and D&D 3.5. Are there any other systems with futuristic tech crafting abilities that would mesh well with the d20 modern and 3.5 systems, increase the power of weapons, reduce crafting DC, reduce cost of crafting, reduce time of crafting, or similar desirable effects that one would want from a weapon? My character specializes in weapons and armor both magical and technological. I've taken all of the abilities that I care for from D20 future. I've looked at Star Wars and Starfinder and can't find any that I really like. Any resources would be helpful.

Comment: What makes a "good" crafting ability?  What makes one crafting ability better or worse than another?

Comment: Typically what's makes one crafting ability better than another is A) not being the same as the other and B) giving a better effect and/or making the process easier. I appreciate your effort to gain clarification and hope that this definition clarifies the information that you were missing

Comment: To be clear, you want *d20 System* class abilities that involve crafting? For example, the *Classic Spycraft* prestige class technocrat at level 6 gets the class feature **smartgun** that, in part, says, "Beginning at 6th level, the technocrat’s base attack bonus is considered to be equal to his agent level when attacking with any medium-sized or smaller non-tactical weapon to which he has personally added at least 1 masterwork modification" (*The Shop* 56–7). That kind of thing?

Comment: Exactly, and now that you've recommended spycraft, the Inventor class has multiple abilities that would be useful for my character.

Comment: OK, that’s clear-er, probably good enough, but I think the odds of getting a good (comprehensive) answer to this are just about nil, because “everything ever printed with d20 System compatibility” is a preposterously enormous potential source list. Also, it’s just such an… unusual idea (just because they’re d20-System-based doesn’t mean they’re balanced around the same power level), so I don’t think you’ll find much of anybody else who has looked at it, and might have a list handy. At any rate, sounds like you’re familiar with 3.5e material and looking for others, so I’ll delete my answer.

Comment: @BDV give PF1e alchemist a look, it is so "good" at crafting it is a little overwhelming.